# core Javascript OAuth2 One Tap Auto Google Login get error

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

i want to use this code but get error 
I have add localhost in web client key

error why [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.

even i have add this url https://quickyhandy.uc.r.appspot.com/ and try with this but still getting same error
this one is added in Client ID for Web application

If you hit this url and can view error in a console[image]

```
<html>
<head>   
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script> 
      <script>
        function init() {
          google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: 'key-key',
            callback: handleCredentialResponse,
            auto_select: true
          });
          google.accounts.id.prompt();
        };
        function handleCredentialResponse(res) {
          console.log(res);
        }
      </script>
  </head>
<body onload="init()">
```